# Deepwater threw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException during training if balance_classes=TRUE

Tags: h2o

In AWS, I followed the instruction in [here](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-amazon-aws-image) and launched a g2.2xlarge EC2 using the community AMI ami-97591381

On the docker image, I can run a simple deepwater tutorial without a problem.  However, when I tried to train a  deepwater model using my own data (which worked ok with a non-GPU deeplearning model), h2o gave me this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 <= 186393 < 170807
    at water.Futures.blockForPending(Futures.java:88)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterDatasetIterator.Next(DeepWaterDatasetIterator.java:99)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterTask.setupLocal(DeepWaterTask.java:168)
    at water.MRTask.setupLocal0(MRTask.java:550)
    at water.MRTask.dfork(MRTask.java:456)
    at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:389)
    at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:385)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.trainModel(DeepWater.java:345)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.buildModel(DeepWater.java:205)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.computeImpl(DeepWater.java:118)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:173)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.compute2(DeepWater.java:111)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1256)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 <= 186393 < 170807
    at water.fvec.Vec.elem2ChunkIdx(Vec.java:925)
    at water.fvec.Vec.chunkForRow(Vec.java:1063)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterDatasetIterator$FrameDataConverter.compute2(DeepWaterDatasetIterator.java:76)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my code, which you can run as I made the S3 links public:

```
library(h2o)
library(jsonlite)
library(curl)

h2o.init()
df.truth <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nw.data.test.us.east/df.truth.zeroed", header = T, sep=",")
df.truth$isFemale <- h2o.asfactor(df.truth$isFemale)
hotnames.truth <- fromJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nw.data.test.us.east/hotnames.json", simplifyVector = T)

# Training and validation sets
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df.truth, c(0.9), seed=1234)
train.truth <- h2o.assign(splits[[1]], "train.truth.hex")   
valid.truth <- h2o.assign(splits[[2]], "valid.truth.hex")

dl.2.balanced <- h2o.deepwater(         
  training_frame = train.truth, model_id="dl.2.balanced",      
  x=setdiff(hotnames.truth[1:(length(hotnames.truth)/2)], c("isFemale", "nwtcs")),
  y="isFemale", stopping_metric = "AUTO", seed = 1000000,
  sparse = F, 
  balance_classes = T,
  mini_batch_size = 20)
```

The h2o version is 3.13.0.356.

**Update:**

I think I found the h2o bug.  If I set **balance_classes** to FALSE, then it will run w/o crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Deep Water is a legacy project (as of December 2017), which means that it is no longer under active development. The H2O.ai team has no current plans to add new features, however, contributions from the community (in the form of pull requests) are welcome.